Countable Choice from Finite Sets
Consider the following 4 statements:

Axiom of countable choice
Axiom of countable choice from finite sets
Axiom of countable choice from Dedekind finite sets
Existence of a choice function for any countable collection of sets when every X in that collection has just two elements

Are there any equivalent statements on the list?
Well, 1 implies 2, 3 and 4. 2 implies 3 and 4. The main difficulty is to construct proofs in the opposite direction. And in most cases I don’t understand where to start proving it.
Consider the case 4 $\longrightarrow$ 2. If we have a countable family $ \{ A_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $, we can try to separate $ \{ X_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ from it in such a way that for any natural number $n$, every $X_n$ contains exactly two elements, say $X_n=\{ x_n, y_n \} $. It means that $ \{ A_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = \{ A'_n \cup X_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $. Then it will be possible to apply 4 to make a choice. But I'm not sure if it's possible to construct such $ \{ X_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in ZF.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

No. (4) is provable from ZF alone; (3) implies that every Dedekind-finite set is finite, but (2) doesn't; and (1) can fail while all the others hold.

@Asaf Karagila I made a mistake in 4. The collection of sets must be countable, not finite.

Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202586/axiom-of-choice-for-sets-of-finite-sets

The correct order of implications is $$(1)\to(3)\to(2)\to(4).$$ And all of these implications are strict.
To note that (3) implies (2), note that every finite set is Dedekind-finite, but not necessarily the other way around. So, let's explore why the reverse implications fail.
1. $(4)\not\to(2)$
There are many results to this effect, and the area is fairly well-understood in terms of "The Axiom of Choice for finite sets of size(s) in $I$" implies "The Axiom of Choice for finite sets of size(s) in $J$" for two sets $I$ and $J$. The proofs and constructions will traditionally be compatible with the restrictions to the Axiom of Countable Choice [for ...].
2. $(2)\not\to(3)$
This is subtle, but fairly easy. In Cohen's first model of the failure of the Axiom of Choice, there is a Dedekind-finite set of reals, $A$. This set can be mapped onto the natural numbers, since every infinite set of reals can be mapped onto the natural numbers. Say $f\colon A\to\omega$ is such a surjection. Then $\{f^{-1}(n)\mid n<\omega\}$ is a countable family of Dedekind-finite sets. However, if this family admits a choice function, then $A$ has a countably infinite subset, as such a choice function must be injective. Therefore we have a countable family of Dedekind-finite sets without a choice function.
On the other hand, every set can be linearly ordered, so if we have any set of finite sets, $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$, fix a linear ordering on $\bigcup A_i$, then each $A_i$ is well-ordered under that linear order, as it is finite, so we can simply choose its minimum. Alternatively, we can prove that in the Cohen model if $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a family of sets where each $A_i$ can be well-ordered, then the whole family admits a choice function. So, these are two arguments for finding a choice function.
3. $(3)\not\to(1)$
Note that if every Dedekind-finite set is finite, then every countable family of finite sets admits a choice function. To see why, if $\{A_n\mid n<\omega\}$ is a family of non-empty finite sets, then $T=\bigcup_{n<\omega}\prod_{k<n}A_k$ is an infinite set, so it is Dedekind-infinite. But it has a natural tree structure where every level is finite, so by fixing a countable subset $T'=\{t_n\mid n<\omega\}\subseteq T$ it must be that the levels $T'$ meets are arbitrarily high in the tree. So we can define $a_n\in A_n$ to be such that $a_n=t_i(n)$ for the least $i$ for which $t_i$ is defined on $n$.
Moreover, under the assumption that every Dedekind-finite set is finite, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are trivially equivalent. So it only remains to show that The Axiom of Countable Choice can fail. But it is known that "Every Dedekind-finite set is finite" is weaker than the Axiom of Countable Choice, so indeed, there is such a model.

Apologies to Calliope for rejecting the edit. That was entirely my fault.

"every infinite set of reals can be mapped onto the natural numbers". That's a nice observation. Do you know who proved it first?

@AndrésE.Caicedo: Not sure. Might be folklore. I know it's part of Sierpinski's proof of Kuratowski's theorem about power sets and surjections onto $\omega$. But it seems too rudimentary to wait until the 1940 to be noticed.
